# Google Drive API - Select Parent

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have successfully implemented a Google Drive API using PHP and I am trying to improve my application.

Is it possible using the GooglePicker to select a parent/folder? I am trying to determine the following:

1. Configure a picker to allow a user to browse the Drive folders they have access to
2. Allow the user to select a folder
3. Return the ID of the folder to be used in additional processing

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not currently available.

For more information, please check the [discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-picker-api/onb8R9sv_vY).